# How to have many namespaces while keeping a 'clean' api? namespace composition

Tags: c++, api, namespaces

**EDIT**: This does not really seem a duplicate to me since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c) in broader in scope (*how to use it*). Anyways, the answer to my question does turn out to be there in paercebal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/81602/1248364) and is **namespace composition**. Another related source in SO is this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871390/why-is-namespace-composition-so-rarely-used).

---

I've been trying to modularize my code using namespaces. Anon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/713717/1248364) to a question on nested namespaces got me wondering whether they should be used for design instead of simply avoiding name clashes.

I feel like namespaces (occasionally nested ones) are useful to organize the code, but sure things like `world::europe::spain::madrid` become cumbersome to use. Therefore, from an API point of view, having most code in the same namespace (just like the `std` library) works best.

My question is then two fold:

1. **Should namespaces be used to organize code or simply to avoid
   name clashes?** and if so
2. **How to have a "complex" namespace structure while keeping the API
   clean?**

Regarding question 2, I've been using the following strategy:

(1) having some code with its own namespace

```
//mathlib.h

namespace mathlib {
    int sum( int a, int b ) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

(2) and bring it into another namespace

```
//otherlib.h

#include <iostream>
#include "mathlib.h"

namespace otherlib {
    using namespace mathlib; // lookup stuff inside mathlib

    void print(int n) {
        std::cout << "the int is " << n << "!";
    }
}
```

(3) So I can actually call `sum` as it were under the `otherlib` namespace.

```
#include "otherlib.h"

int main(){
    auto myint = otherlib::sum(1, 2);
    otherlib::print(myint);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside from ADL I can't think of any. Of course, from a personal style point of view I wouldn't personally nest so many namespaces.

Comment: @Johnsyweb. Opps, you're right. In those cases should I delete the post or simply edit it?

Comment: @dudu, Do not delete it. Let it be as it is. If moderator feels the need, your question will be closed. But still the heading of your question is searchable in Google

Comment: If you bring too many things into other namespaces, you may end up with the problem you tried to avoid (name clashes).